# How to create multiple relationships between 2 models?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using: Ember 2.5.1, Ember Data 2.5.2 with the JSONAPIAdapter

I am creating an application to track inter-store stock transfers.

I have a table called **transfers**:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
| id | from_store_id | to_store_id | transfer_notes |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 12            | 32          | transfer to 32 |
| 2  | 9             | 13          | transfer to 13 |
| 3  | 32            | 9           | transfer to 9  |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Each row represents a transfer and it's origin and destination stores.

I also have a table called **stores**:

```
+-----+----------+-------------+------------+
| id  | store_no | store_state | store_city |
+-----+----------+-------------+------------+
| 12  | tx12     | TX          | Dallas     |
| 9   | me09     | ME          | Bangor     |
| 32  | wa32     | WA          | Yakima     |
| 13  | tn13     | TN          | Memphis    |
+-----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

It seems to me that the relationships between these two tables are:

1. A transfer belongs to a (origin) store
2. A transfer **also** belongs to a (destination) store
3. A store can have many transfers as both origin and destination store.

How can I define these relationships in Ember Data?

I recently picked Ember back up after a 3 year break and I am pretty confused as to how to define these relationships or if they are even correct. One of the things that is really throwing me off is the custom names of the *from_store_id* and *to_store_id* in the **transfers** table.

Any insights welcome.

If it matters I am using Sinatra with [JSONAPI::Serializers](https://github.com/fotinakis/jsonapi-serializers#jsonapiserializers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define different relationships inside one model, even with itself. There is more information in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/relationships/#toc_explicit-inverses)

In this case, you would do something like this:

```
//model storehouse.js
export default Model.extend({
  transferOrigins:hasMany('transfer', { inverse: 'storeOrigin' }),
  transferDestinations:hasMany('transfer', { inverse: 'storeDestination' }),
  storeNo:attr('string'),
  storeState:attr('string'),
  storeCity:attr('string')
});

//model transfer.js
export default Model.extend({
  storeOrigin:belongsTo('storehouse'),
  storeDestination:belongsTo('storehouse'),
  fromStoreId:attr('string'),
  toStoreId:attr('string'),
  transferNotes:attr('string')
});
```

Since you have multiple relationships with the same model, you help `ember-data` to understand which property is related with using `inverse`.

Here you have a full example in this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8460f197cd852750f5c7fdcede175c68?numColumns=2&openFiles=models.storehouse.js%2Cmodels.transfer.js)

Comment: As I was looking at this further I tried to figure out how Ember-Data knew which keys map to each other in order to create the relationships.

I seems that this example works because you have a **fromStoreId** AND and **toStoreId** in the **storehouse** model.

Is it absolutely necessary to define two keys for the storehouse model? They will always be the same. In my model definition I only list a **id** column in my **stores** table. Each store should only have one id or is this something I have to do for this relationship to work?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I copied the same model twice. I've edited the answer and the ember-twiddle. You don't need `fromStoreId` and `toStoreId` in the `storehouse` model, they were attributes of the `transfer` model.